# AngularJS - Inherit ngModel in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a custom directive like this:

myText.html:

```
<div>
<label>{{label}}</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive("myText", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "shared/form/myText.html",
        scope : {
            label : "@",
        }
    };
});
```

I just want to wrap an input and handle a label as an attribute.

In my view i use the directive this way:

```
<my-text label="Name" ng-model="person.firstname"></my-text>
```

The problem is that ng-model is not binding the model to my input.

What is the correct way to achieve this result?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `ng-model` on the input and bind it to the isolate scope.

```
<my-text label=Name model=person.firstname></my-text>

<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model=model>

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "shared/form/myText.html",
    scope : {
        label : "@",
        model: "=",
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I use a new attribute name such as 'model' or 'ngModel'  as a best practice? I tried { model : "=ngModel"} and that worked...

Comment: @Rob80 I would use a name that makes sense and also try not to overload existing directive names